# How to handle this class visibility issue?

Tags: java, performance, tree, binary-search-tree

I have a BinarySearchTree implementation which implements public `insert` method of interface `Tree` as follows.

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Tree<T> {
public boolean insert(T value) {
Node<T> nodeInserted = insertValue(value); //call private method to insert. 
 return (nodeInserted != null);
}

 protected Node<T> insertValue(T value) {
   //insert the node and then return it.
 }

 public Node<T> search(T value) {
        //search and return node.
    }

   //Node class for BST
  public static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    // Fields and getters and setters.
   }
}
```

The idea is that other derived classes (e.g. AVL) tree will override the method insertValue as:
`

```
public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>> extends BinarySearchTree<T> {
 @Override
    protected Node<T> insertValue(T id) {
       //specific code to insert node in AVL
    }

 // AVL Node
  public static class AVLNode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<T> {
    // Fields and getters/ setters
  }
}
```

Now I have another class TreeMap which can be implemented using RB Tree or AVL Tree. I am trying to reuse the code of AVL as:

```
public class TreeMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Map<K,V> {
  private AVLTree<K> tree = null;

  @Override
  public V put(K key, V value) {
    //Here is the problem. 
  }
}
```

The problem is: I want to insert key property as a node in AVL Tree and then need to get hold of the inserted node and do some processing work. I can neither override nor get hold of insertValue() of AVLTree class.

One option it to call insert method and get boolean result. Check if it is true then again call search method to get the node and then do processing. Is there any other better solution for this problem?

I need one more suggestion. I have declared class `Node` static as its related to `BST` only. I need another node class for AVL and thought of extending static class Node. For making Node visible in another package I had to declare public so that it is available for AVLNode as well. Is there any design issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

What if `insert` returned `null` instead of `false` and the node found instead of `true` ? Then you would be able to return both information in a single shot. An even better idea would be to return an `Optional<T>`.

For your second question, I actually find it weird to extend Node from another class' static inner class. You said `Node` onlye concerned `BST`, but if you need it in `AVL` that's not the case, so you'd better have two separate classes or a single interface/abstract class extended by bothon `BST.Node` and `AVL.Node`.

Comment: AN object of Node should be closely related to BinarySearchTree and that is why it is static nested class. AVLTree also needs node class which is also Node so I found it suitable to extend Node.

If Node is protected I can not see it in another packages where AVLTree is defined, so had to make it public. And then it extends static nested class Node.


IMHO, I believe we don't have static inner classes in Java. Don't we?

Comment: Used like that, I don't know, but otherwise it is a quite common thing : Map.Entry (public interface), HashMap.Node (private class used as an implentation detail), Rectangle2D.Double and Rectangle2D.Float (public, used to provide the same features for both double and float precision)... What disturbs me in your case is that it seems to be an implementation detail so I would not expect it to be public

Comment: I thought of using Node like a private static class only as Node class in HashMap. Now AVLNode is also Node so I thought of extending Node class, but if it is private (or protected) it will not be available for derived class AVLTree in some other package.

SO even I could not think of any other neat solution.

Comment: insert() method cannot return null instead of false as this method is part of interface Tree and signature specifies return type as boolean. SO cannot change.

Comment: @akhil_mittal Yes, but can't you change your interface ? That's what I meant. If you are using Java 8, you can even return an `Optional<T>`, otherwise you can implement this simple class by yourself or use this implementation http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Optional.java#Optional and remove what you don't need in it

Comment: Agree I can use Optional in Java 8, rather I am using Java 8 only :).

But interface cannot be changed easily as it is implemented at many places.

Comment: @akhil_mittal I see... maybe it is worth doing it, it is up to you.